# error while running php artisan backup:run

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, symfony, xampp

Hi every one I am currently working on laravel 5.8 and recently installed spatie/laravel-backup package to backup my files and db and i did all the steps which are needed to use the package but when I run the command
`php artisan backup:run` it gives many errors as below

> Starting backup... Dumping database u452010341_qkcg... Backup failed
>   because The dump process failed with exitcode 1 : General error :
>   '"mysqldump"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

```
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\spatie\db-dumper\src\DbDumper.php(246): Spatie\DbDumper\Exceptions\DumpFailed::processDidNotEndSuccessfully(Object(Symfony\Component\Process\Process))
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\spatie\db-dumper\src\Databases\MySql.php(190): Spatie\DbDumper\DbDumper->checkIfDumpWasSuccessFul(Object(Symfony\Component\Process\Process), 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\spatie\laravel-backup\src\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob.php(250): Spatie\DbDumper\Databases\MySql->dumpToFile('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#3 [internal function]: Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob->Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Backup\{closure}(Object(Spatie\DbDumper\Databases\MySql), 'mysql')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php(1120): array_map(Object(Closure), Array, Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\spatie\laravel-backup\src\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob.php(253): Illuminate\Support\Collection->map(Object(Closure))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\spatie\laravel-backup\src\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob.php(167): Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob->dumpDatabases()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\spatie\laravel-backup\src\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob.php(143): Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob->createBackupManifest()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\spatie\laravel-backup\src\Commands\BackupCommand.php(52): Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob->run()
#9 [internal function]: Spatie\Backup\Commands\BackupCommand->handle()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(32): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(90): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(576): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(183): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php(255): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(170): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\spatie\laravel-backup\src\Commands\BaseCommand.php(16): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(1012): Spatie\Backup\Commands\BaseCommand->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(272): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Spatie\Backup\Commands\BackupCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(148): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php(90): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(133): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#24 {main}
Backup failed because: The dump process failed with exitcode 1 : General error : '"mysqldump"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I searched for solutions and found the code below:

```
    'connections' => [ 
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql'
        ...,
        'dump' => [
           'dump_binary_path' => '/path/to/the/binary', // only the path, so without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`
           'use_single_transaction',
           'timeout' => 60 * 5, // 5 minute timeout
           'exclude_tables' =>['table1', 'table2'],`enter code here`
           'add_extra_option' =>'--optionname=optionvalue', 
        ]  
    ],
```

But still I'm getting same error... I tried more than 100times, still nothing.
So any one who gone through this problem or any body who knows how to solve this please help me out.

Comment: Does your `/path/to/the/binary'` contains the `mysqldump` executable?

Comment: Have you even **read** that error message? Isn't it pretty clear about the missing binary?

Answer (score 1):

in the code you found, where says:

```
'dump_binary_path' => '/path/to/the/binary',
```

Change to:

```
'dump_binary_path' => 'C:\xampp\mysql\bin',
```

Next time, look to the errors because int his case, the problem is well described!

Regards

Comment: yes sir i did the same but i am still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

Now you also need to comment this line:
//'add_extra_option' =>'--optionname=optionvalue',

working for me.